# Inherit color and underline color on links

Tags: css

I'm having problems getting the green color applied to the anchor element (`a`) within `#container`.

In this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lasseedsvik/DnhHb/2/

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <a href="">Green</a>
</p>

<div id="container">
<p>
    <a href="">Green also</a>
</p>
<p>
    <div><div><a href="">Also Green</a></div></div>
</p>
<p>
    <h3><a href="">Red</a></h3>
</p>
<p>
    <span style="color:yellow"><a href="">Yellow</a></span>
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    font-size: inherit;
}

a {
    color: green;
}

#container a {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;    
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
}

h3 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

I've managed to get close by using the inherit property on `#container a` but the problem is that the 2nd and 3rd link dont "fall back" to the green color.

My original problem which is almost solved here, was that links that had `<h2>` or other colors that differed from green but always had a green text-decoration.

The content in the container is generated by a WYSIWYG-editor so I don't have much control over its content.

Comment: You'll want to show the code demonstrating the problem, rather than a test case where the problem doesn't even manifest itself.

Comment: The problem I think is because `inherit` inherits color from the parent and in this case `#container` doesn't have a color specified. Try adding `color: green` to `#container`. For the red colored link and yellow colored link, their respective parents have the color specified.

Comment: what happen with my ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174020/inherit-color-and-underline-color-on-links/19174134#19174134

Comment: @KarSho: What do you mean what happened? It's still there...?

Comment: @Harry yes. So only asking.

Comment: Please close this subject, I'll ask again in a better way after some coffee. Sorry all for confusion

Comment: @BoltClock If my ans is not sense means, what about this question?

Comment: @KarSho: You have misunderstood BoltClock's comment. He hasn't stated anywhere that your answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem looked like this:

By specifying the following CSS:

```
a { color: green; }
#container a { color: inherit; }
```

The OP wanted to have a default green color for `<a>` elements, **unless its ancestors have a set color**, in which case the `<a>` element should inherit.

```
<a> was colored green
<.. id="container"> <*> <a> was colored black
<h3 style="color: red"> <a> should be colored red
<span style="color: yellow"> <a> should be colored yellow.
```

The problem was that the second `<a>` above should be colored **green**, instead of **black**. The reason it is rendered black, is because there is no such thing as an HTML element with undefined color, since the browser's default CSS, adds a computed style which makes it black.

What the OP initially wanted could be named **Selective CSS Inheritance**, which after a lot of research, seems impossible with the current CSS implementation.

The above could be easily done if CSS implemented a keyword/property value similar to `inherit`, possibly called `inherit-user-defined`, which would only inherit values from user-set, non browser-set styles.

I know that this doesn't actually answer the question, but I think it will be useful for readers that will search for this, since the question's accepted answer was unexpected for some of us.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the rule for

```
#container a {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;    
}
```

Comment: That will make all links green. They should inherit the color, and same color for text-decoration

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DnhHb/3/)

use

```
* {
    font-size: inherit;
}

a {
    color: green;
}

#container a {

}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
}

h3 a{
    color: red;
    font-size: 28px !important;
}
span a{
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Since you accepted this.. you basically just wanted an answer using more specific selectors? And the usage of `!important`?

Comment: The OP wants it to work in a WYSIWYG editor, with unknown content structure, not to add every possible combination of elements and `<a>`, as far as I understand.

Comment: @JoshC and mavrosxristoforos: +1, was just about to post the same. This doesn't look like a feasible solution based on what is stated in the question. But then when OP has accepted, I guess we have to leave it at that.

Comment: @Harry Yea - this doesn't technically answer the question - even though it wasn't a very good one.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/DnhHb/5/

I just Removed the `color:inherit` from `Container a` Class

Comment: How is this any different to KarSho's answer?

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos nothing. no changes.

Comment: Is it??? I din notice dude...Its my answer. The answer is always Will be same because its solution is one

Answer (score 0):

add this css:

```
#container p a {
    color: green;
}

#container div a {
    color: green;
}

#container span a {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Now remove the inline css since it is not needed.

Reason: since you told it to inherit, you need to explicitly declare each instance, i.e. you need to say `#container p a` needs to be green.

See it fixed:
http://jsfiddle.net/DnhHb/6/

Also see a better formatted version:
http://jsfiddle.net/DnhHb/9/

Comment: This renders the last `<a>` (in `<span style="color: yellow;">`) green.